# React hooks - state in useState() is not reset when route is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-hooks

```
const Create = () => {
  console.log('rerender !!')
  const [parcelType, setParcelType] = useState('paper')
  console.log('parcelType =', parcelType)

  return (
    <Container onClick={() => setParcelType('plastic')}>
      <BookingList />
      <Card title="Business">
        <p>Header</p>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Create
```

I want to change parcelType state to 'plastic' when click on Container in Create component. and I want to reset parcelType state to 'paper' when route is change ( Create component re-render ). But when component re-render state is not set to paper

For more details: CreateComponent is re-render when route is change in BookingList component

```
 const BookingList = props => {
  const { id } = props.match.params
  const containerStyle = useTranslateSpring('-100px', '0')

  const itemList = items.map((item, idx) => {
    const itemStyle = useTranslateSpring('-100px', '0', '0', 200 + 200 * idx)
    const url = `/booking/${item.id}/create`

    return (
      <ItemContainer
        onClick={() => props.history.push(url)}
        style={itemStyle}
        key={item.id}
        isactive={id === item.id}
      >
        {item.id}
      </ItemContainer>
    )
  })
  return <Container style={containerStyle}>{itemList}</Container>
}

export default withRouter(BookingList)
```

Create Component is render in route by routeTemplate

```
const Routes = () => (
 <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}>
   <> 
    <RouteTemplate
    exact
    path="/booking/:id/create"
    component={Booking.create}
    title="Booking"
    />
   </>
 </Router>
)
```

and RouteTemplate is render Component wrapped by PageTemplate component

```
  const RouteTemplate = props => {
  const {
    component: Component,
    title,
    query,
    isAuthenticated,
    isLanding,
    ...rest
  } = props

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={matchProps =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <PageTemplate title={title} isLanding={isLanding}>
            <Component {...matchProps} query={query} />
          </PageTemplate>
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/',
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: When and where do you render Create component

Comment: Thank you I already add more information in post. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: okay so one more question when you change the route by clicking on ItemContainer, from say `booking/1/create` to `booking/2/create` the create component is re-rendered. and not what I want to know is that in createComponent's Container onClick you change the state to plastic or you want to change it when the container is re-rendered with different id?

Comment: I want to change it to 'plastic' when click on Container in Create component.
and I want to reset parcelType state to 'paper' when route is change ( Create component re-render )

Comment: so in other words you want component(its state particularly) be reset once route is changed, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I assume you want to reset component's state once route is changed.

This should happen wherever you use functional component + hooks or class-based component with explicit `this.state`. It's how React works under the hood.

1. You already have `<Create>` rendered at the page
2. Once route is changed `<Route>` tries to render `<Create>` element
3. *React sees there is already existing `<Create>` element* and tries to update that instead of re-creating(typically update is much more efficient than re-creating). That's why state is not reset - since it should not reset for updates.

There are different way to handle that.

If such a case happen outside react-router's `<Route>` I'd suggest [use `key`](https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e) prop to reset state. But for `<Route>` it would mean replacing more clear/straightforward `<Route path="..." component={Create} />` with more verboose `<Route path="..." render={({match}) => <Create match={match} key={match.params.id} />}`

So instead let's apply `useEffect` hook to reset state once `props.match.params.id` is changed:

```
const Create = ({ match: {params: {id} } }) => {    

  useEffect(() => {
    setParcelType('paper');
  }, [id]);
```

That should be equal to class-based

```
state = {
  typeOfWhatEver: 'paper'
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    this.setState({
      typeOfWhatEver: 'paper'
    });
  }
}
```